# Python igraph: Fastest way to convert large graph to python-igraph graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, igraph

I have a large undirected weighted graph with ~375,000 nodes and ~3,400,000 edges represented as adjacency list (dictionary of dictionaries).

e.g.

```
A --> (B,2), (C,4)
B --> (A,2)
C --> (A,4)
```

is represented as

```
{A : {B : 2, C : 4}, B : {A : 2}, C : {A : 4}}
```

I want to convert this graph to python-igraph graph and subsequently run walktrap community detection algorithm. I have tried following approach:

```
g = igraph.Graph()

for node in mygrpah.keys():
    g.add_vertex(name=node) # each node is a string

for node,neighbours in mygraph.iteritems():
    g.add_edges([(node,neighbour) for neighbour in neighbours.keys()])
    for neighbour in neighbours.keys():
        # to avoid adding edge while traversing neighbour's dictionary
        del mygraph[neighbour][node]
```

I tested this on a subgraph with 150,000 nodes and it took ~11 hours on my computer with 4GB RAM and i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz × 4 processor.

1. is there a better approach to do the conversion?
2. is there any other graph library which is faster and provides support for walktrap community detection algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you add one edge after another, which is very time consuming due to the underlying data structure. It's much faster to first build a list of vertices and a list of edges and then add all edges with one call to `add_edges(...)`.

```
mygraph = {"A" : {"B" : 2, "C" : 4}, "B" : {"A" : 2}, "C" : {"A" : 4}, "D":{}}
g = igraph.Graph(directed=False)
g.add_vertices(mygraph.keys())
edges = [(start, end) for start in mygraph.keys() for end in mygraph[start].keys()]
# or if you only want to have undirected links only once:
edges = [edge for edge in edges if edge[0] > edge[1]]
g.add_edges(edges)
igraph.plot(g)
```